# Virtualbox shutdown screen effect

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, visual-effects

When user tries to close virtual machine Virtualbox adds that nice greyed out effect on the virtual machine screen.

Here's what I mean":

[image]

How such effect is called? I tried to search for it but without any luck. Is there any way to use such effect for an image? Except for taking screenshot of Virtualbox machine?

Comment: Grey filter? ...

Comment: It's not only greyed out, there are those horizontal stripes as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that this would be a simple gray filter (or perhaps "overlay") with a [scanline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scan_line) effect. And yes, you can certainly apply such effects to an image